# How to prevent document.body.scrollHeight changing when rendering components with variable height?

Tags: css, vue.js, scroll, vuejs3, css-transitions

I am having a one page landing page with elements who enter when the page is scrolled down. This is achieved with `vue transitions`. Problem is that the elements have `variable element heights` (f.e. paragraph), which makes the `scrollHeight` of the document change, whenever an element transitions in. I think for this case `v-show` was invented but it only seems to work with `static element heights`. As soon as the element height differs from the static reserved space (element's `min-height`) of `v-show`, the `scrollHeight` changes and the page jumps.

The only workaround I was able to find was by dumping `vue transitions` and instead use purely `CSS` and `opacity` property, basically hiding the elements and fade them in when element scrolls into viewport.

Is there any way to use `vue transitions` for this without the `document scrollHeight` changing, leading to an unpleasant "scroll jump"?

Comment: Couldn't you use an opacity change, rather than a height change? Common CSS trick solving the transition of a height issue in CSS.

Comment: Could you elaborate?